# Rails - has_many through: set join model foreign key when adding to collection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have these associations:

**character.rb**

```
has_many :messagechats, dependent: :destroy
has_many :messageconversations, through: :messagechats, source: :conversation
```

**messagechat.rb**

```
belongs_to :character
belongs_to :conversation, class_name: 'Messageconversation', foreign_key: 'conversation_id'
```

**messageconversation.rb**

```
has_many :chats, class_name: 'Messagechat', dependent: :destroy
has_many :characters, through: :chats, source: :character
```

The `Messagechat` model in the database does have a `conversation_id` column, not a `messageconversation_id` column.

I'm trying to add a `character` to a `@messageconversation` with:

```
@messageconversation.characters << character
```

But this is throwing this error:

```
ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute 'messageconversation_id' for Messagechat.)
```

because `<<` assumes the `foreign_key` in the join model will be derived from `messageconversation` (ie `messageconversation_id`). I need the `foreign_key` to be `conversation_id`. What is the correct syntax to set the `foreign_key` using `<<`? Or is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I think you should fix your file and class names to indicate the spaces, i.e, `message_conversation.rb` and `class MessageConversation/:message_conversation`.

You should be able to specify the foreign key where you define the association.  See the rails guide for [foreign_key options](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to-foreign-key).

UPDATE: I made a new app with your models, hopefully it helps illustrates.

```
class MessageChat < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :character
  belongs_to :conversation, class_name: 'MessageConversation'
end

class MessageConversation < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :chats,
           class_name: 'MessageChat',
           dependent: :destroy,
           foreign_key: :conversation_id
  has_many :characters, through: :chats
end

class Character < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :message_chats, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :message_conversations, through: :message_chats, source: :conversation
end
```

This has all the associations you're looking for (as far as I can tell) working.

```
irb(main):002:0> conversation = MessageConversation.create
=> #<MessageConversation id: 5>
irb(main):003:0> character = Character.create
=> #<Character id: 5>
irb(main):004:0> conversation.characters << character
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Character id: 5>]>
irb(main):005:0> character.message_chats
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<MessageChat id: 2, character_id: 5, conversation_id: 5>]>
```

Comment: I added `foreign_key: 'conversation_id'` to `Messagechat` but the error remains. And yes, the `Messagechat` model in the database does have a `conversation_id` column, not a `messageconversation_id` column.

Comment: Is there any reason you aren't calling that model `Conversation` instead of `MessageConversation`? It seems like an arbitrary change that's also complicating things for you.

Comment: Yes, because I also have a `Post` model which is very similar to my `Message` model, and this simplifies things elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you! I needed to add `foreign_key: 'conversation_id'` to the `Messageconversation` class. Now `<<` works as expected.